# Corona sdk - native.newTextField - lose focus

Tags: lua, sdk, coronasdk

what I want to accomplish is when I create a native.newTextField set the isSecure option to false and the placeholder to "type your password"

and whenever a user start typing, change the textfield to isSecure = true, to have the * symbols. 
with my approach I have the problem that my textfield lose focus after the first letter.

here is my code:

```
local function fieldHandler( event )
    if ( "began" == event.phase ) then
        -- This is the "keyboard has appeared" event
        -- In some cases you may want to adjust the interface when the keyboard appears.
    elseif ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
        -- This event is called when the user stops editing a field: for example, when they touch a different field
        if(event.target.id == "password" and event.target.text == "")then
            event.target.isSecure = false
            passwordField.placeholder = "type your password"
        end

    elseif ( "editing" == event.phase ) then
        if(event.target.id == "password" and string.len(event.target.text) >0 ) then
            event.target.isSecure = true
            --native.setKeyboardFocus( event.target )   
        end
    elseif ( "submitted" == event.phase ) then

        -- Hide keyboard
        native.setKeyboardFocus( nil )
    end
```

end

--scene:show
--Did

```
        local passwordField = native.newTextField( _CX - fieldWidth/2, passwordFieldBg.y, fieldWidth, 40 )
    passwordField.id = "password"
    passwordField:addEventListener( "userInput", fieldHandler ) 
    group:insert( passwordField)
    passwordField.hasBackground = false
    passwordField.anchorX = 0
    passwordField.placeholder = "type your password"
    passwordField.autocorrectionType = "UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo"
    passwordField.isSecure = false
    passwordField.font =  native.newFont( gM.fontDin )
    passwordField:resizeFontToFitHeight()
```

please help me to solve this, or another approach that I could use.

thanks,

Version 2016.2883 (2016.5.17)

Comment: Why are you changing isSecure values? Keep it always `true`, it does not interfere in the `placeholder`.

Comment: it does interfere at least the way I was doing it.
if I call the placeholder first and then isSecure, The text of the placeholder vanish.
Before: --Here the placeholder text reset to ""
  passwordField.placeholder = "type your password"
  passwordField.isSecure = true

After: --Here the placeholder text keeps his value.
  passwordField.isSecure = true
  passwordField.placeholder = "type your password"

thanks for helping me figuring that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not necessary to change the `isSecure` value, but you can move this to `began` phase:

```
if ( "began" == event.phase ) then
    -- This is the "keyboard has appeared" event
    -- In some cases you may want to adjust the interface when the keyboard appears.
    if (event.target.id == "password") then
        event.target.isSecure = true
```

Comment: it does interfere at least the way I was doing it.
if I call the placeholder first and then isSecure, The text of the placeholder vanish.
Before: --Here the placeholder text reset to ""
  passwordField.placeholder = "type your password"
  passwordField.isSecure = true

After: --Here the placeholder text keeps his value.
  passwordField.isSecure = true
  passwordField.placeholder = "type your password"

thanks @Maicon Feldhaus for helping me figuring that out.